# Crop TIFF file with Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, geopandas, satellite

I have a TIFF file. It is necessary to cut the TIFF file at the given coordinates (like in example below).  I've been looking for a few days and haven't found a suitable solution.

How can I resolve this?

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              26.323586194745644,
              51.5136424962856
            ],
            [
              26.318436259612497,
              51.51043743329282
            ],
            [
              26.32558894729766,
              51.50830059935572
            ],
            [
              26.333599957503935,
              51.51168387347343
            ],
            [
              26.323586194745644,
              51.5136424962856
            ]
          ]
        ],
        "type": "Polygon"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

One of the examples that I found:

```
import os
from itertools import product
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio import windows

in_path = 'images'
input_filename = 'B12.tiff'

out_path = 'result/B12'
output_filename = 'tile_{}-{}.tif'


def get_tiles(ds, width=256, height=256):
    nols, nrows = ds.meta['width'], ds.meta['height']
    offsets = product(range(0, nols, width), range(0, nrows, height))
    big_window = windows.Window(col_off=0, row_off=0, width=nols, height=nrows)
    for col_off, row_off in offsets:
        window = windows.Window(col_off=col_off, row_off=row_off, width=width, height=height).intersection(big_window)
        transform = windows.transform(window, ds.transform)
        yield window, transform


with rio.open(os.path.join(in_path, input_filename)) as inds:
    tile_width, tile_height = 256, 256

    meta = inds.meta.copy()

    for window, transform in get_tiles(inds):
        print(window)
        meta['transform'] = transform
        meta['width'], meta['height'] = window.width, window.height
        outpath = os.path.join(out_path,output_filename.format(int(window.col_off), int(window.row_off)))
        with rio.open(outpath, 'w', **meta) as outds:
            outds.write(inds.read(window=window))
```

The second example that I found

```
import fiona
import geopandas
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from rasterio.plot import show
from shapely.geometry import shape

with fiona.open('cords.geojson') as f:
    pol = f.next()
    geom = shape(pol['geometry'])

points = [Polygon(geom)]

print(geom)

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame([1], geometry=points, crs=4326)
print(f'gdf === {gdf}')

src = rasterio.open('images/B03.tiff')

extent = [src.bounds]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
print(extent)
ax = rasterio.plot.show(src, extent=extent, ax=ax, cmap='pink', title='My plot')

gdf.plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. You've pasted a ton of code, but not given any indication of what it's doing, or what it is doing wrong. A focused problem statement is necessary to get an answer here.

Comment: what is your actual question? Both of the examples you post will do what you achieve, so can you explain why it's not "working" as you would like

Comment: @GeoMonkey I want to crop a part of tiff file with a given coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

###### You can cut a raster using GDAL, check at this code:

```
# Import modules

from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo.gdal import gdalconst

# inputpath raster

inputpath = r'inputpath_raster_name.tif' # format: '.tif'

# inputpath geometry

shapefile = r'outputpath_geometry_name.shp' # (ESRI Shapefile, geojson, etc...) format: '.shp', '.geojson', etc...

# Outputpath to Save clip raster

outputpath  = r'outputpath_save_clip_raster_name.tif' # format: '.tif'
```

###### Use a irregular geometry

```
clip = gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS = outputpath, 
                 srcDSOrSrcDSTab  = inputpath, 
                 cutlineDSName    = shapefile, # or geojson
                 cropToCutline    = True,
                 copyMetadata     = True,
                 dstNodata        = 0)      # Select the nodata value
clip = None
```

###### Use the image extent (bounds)

```
clip =  gdal.Warp(destNameOrDestDS = outputpath, 
                  srcDSOrSrcDSTab  = inputpath,
                  outputBounds     = (minx, miny, maxx, maxy),
                  cropToCutline    = True,
                  copyMetadata     = True)

clip = None
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you store your polygon in a variable (let's call it `polygon`), you can just use the following to get the dataset clipped:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
g = gdal.Warp("output.tif", "input.tif",
              cropToCutline=True, cutlineDSName=polygon)
```

You can also read it in memory without worrying about saving it as a file:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
g = gdal.Warp("", "input.tif", format="MEM",
              cropToCutline=True, cutlineDSName=polygon)
```

I can't remember whether your GeoTIFF and polygon need to have the same projection. If they don't have the same projection, you just transforom the vector to match the raster's projection:

```py
g = gdal.VectorTranslate("roi_reproj.geojson", poly,
 dstSRS="EPSG:XXXX", format="GeoJSON")
g = None
```

where you'd use the [EPSG code](https://spatialreference.org) of the raster's projection, and you can just use the output filename (`roi_reproj.geojson`) to clip the raster as above.